# Creating a safe dynamic SQL statement in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to create a safe dynamic SQL statement. I have something currently that creates a dynamic sql statement. I want to see if there is a good way to keep it dynamic and avoid any risk of SQL Injection. I have looked into using a parameterized query, however, you can't exactly make the table name and columns as parameters. My application is a NodeJS/Express api application using mssql. This has the ability to create parameterized queries, but I'm not quite sure how I would handle the table name and column names. I'm trying to move from a C# Linq application to Node to run on docker. Probably irrelevant, but I figure a generic function would help save time to move this over, however SQL Injection is a thing and I want to avoid it. This is how I currently have it written.

```
//table = Table Name, values = {a: 1, b: 2}, wheres = {id: 5}
var update = (table, values, wheres) => {
    var query = `UPDATE ` + table + `\n SET `
    Object.keys(values).forEach(function (key) {
        if(typeof values[key] === "string"){
            query += key + ` = \'` + values[key] + `\', `
        } else {
            query += key + ` = ` + values[key] + `, `
        }
    })
    //removes extra comma and space
    query = query.substring(0, query.length - 2) + `\nWHERE `
    Object.keys(wheres).forEach(function (key) {
        if(typeof wheres[key] === "string"){
            query += key + ` = \'` + wheres[key] + `\' AND `
        } else {
            query += key + ` = ` + wheres[key] + ` AND `
        }
    })
    //removes extra AND with spaces
    query = query.substring(0, query.length - 5)
    return query
}
```

Comment: This has the look of a generic update. This is generally not really a good way to handle data. It is like making a method in c# that can do any number of things by the parameters being passed. I would prefer to get the sql out of the application and back in the database. This is usually done with stored procedures. Then you pass parameters to your procedure instead of dynamically deciding which table to update. You can dynamically decide which procedure to call though from the application.

Comment: So in C# we typically would have a generic repository which is basically what I am trying to mock. With a generic repository you would be able to CRUD on any table really and because it's done using Linq it works very well to avoid any type of injection, however how it creates the SQL is beyond me. Anyways, I think I understand what you are saying, however every single time a column is updated you will have to make sure you update the Stored Proc as well. This still may be the best way to go though, but considering I would have to build a stored proc for each it doesn't help with speed.